# Найти число в питоне

Tags: python

поиск суммы чисел от 1 до n
где n- любое натуральное число

Comment: В чём собственно проблема-то?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(raw_input())
ans = (n+1)*n/2
print ans
```

если python 2.7, а если 3.7, то

```
n = int(input())
ans = (n+1)*n/2
print(ans)
```

P.S. Пользуйтесь эти сайтом, когда у вас ошибка, которую вы не можете решить, а не когда вы не знаете, что делать!

Comment: P.S. годный, только вам бы следовало удалить свой ответ, а то минусов еще больше получите.